# Que signifie bout à bout?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Que signifie l'expression « bout à bout », comme dans cet exemple :

*Les questions des élèves sont mises **bout à bout***.

Comment: Note that it should be “sont miseS”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others said *mettre bout à bout* means to put some things together, sometimes it is use to explain the idea that putting some little things together create something big.

> Would you believe the human body has so many miles of blood vessels
> inside of it, they could go around the Earth more than twice? [From Sang](http://sang.ca)
>
> Savais-tu que, mis **bout à bout**, les vaisseaux sanguins sont deux fois plus longs que la circonférence de la Terre ?

It seems that the expression "end to end" exists in english, as is [Cloverleaf](http://cloverleaf.ca):

> Cut the block of cream cheese in half horizontally; place the cheese
> slabs side by side or **end to end** on microwaveable serving plate.
>
> Déposer les deux morceaux côte à côte ou **bout à bout** sur une assiette de service allant au micro-ondes.

Note that you also encounter in this sentence *côte à côte* (side by side), which is also very common in French.

---

> Les questions des élèves sont mises bout à bout.

In your sentence, it could mean that students will ask there questions one after the other ; or they all wrote their questions, and then we grouped (on a sheet of paper, ...).

Answer (score 3):

This means *in a row*: *placer bout à bout* means that you place the *bout* (extremity) of one thing right next to the *bout* of another thing, usually so that they line up.

Answer (score 2):

'Bout à bout'  veut simplement dire 'les uns derrière les autres'  pour quoi que ce soit, aussi bien des questions que des morceaux à cuire dans vos exemples.

Answer (score 1):

À cette [extrémité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bout/1) du sens, il s'agit d'un emploi au figuré qu'on associait à l'origine à l'idée d'énumérer ou de faire état d'un assemblage, qu'on retrouvait à [*Ac.4*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/bout) (1762), « de certaines choses qui ne sont presque rien, à les prendre séparément; mais qui font un tout considérable regardées ensemble » : « Si on mettoit bout à bout le chemin qu'il fait tous les jours dans son jardin, il se trouveroit qu'au bout de l'année il auroit fait plus de cinq cents lieues. ». Cet emploi abstrait est [attribué](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/bout/1) à l'Académie française (1718, TLFi/DHLF), qui le note au figuré et familier dans *[Ac.8](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/bout/1)* puis au figuré uniquement dans [*Ac.9*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/bout/1) mais sans parler d'énumération ou d'assemblage, se contentant de l'exemple « Nous réussirons en mettant nos efforts bout à bout. ». [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bout/10733/locution?q=bout%20%C3%A0%20bout#160516) parle d'un sens de *bout à bout* comme des choses *ajoutées les unes aux autres*.

---

*Les questions des élèves sont mises bout à bout* ? Ça implique peut-être un format particulier, un affichage, une sortie papier ? Ou est-ce simplement l'idée générique de la somme : mettre *ensemble* ? On ne sait pas exactement, on le trouve imprécis sans davantage de contexte. Avec le papier on peut imaginer enligner les feuilles les unes après les autres. En fusionnant toutes les questions en un seul document, on obtiendra un document contenant la somme des caractères des questions individuelles, qui pourront se suivre en ce qui a trait à l'ordre de leur présentation, à leur séquence...  Si on veut parler de la relation entre une question supplémentaire qui s'ajoute à un ensemble de questions préexistantes, on peut sans doute parler d'ordre chronologique, de haut en bas, sur plusieurs/un grand nombre de pages etc.

Comment: p.s. _enligner les feuilles_.

Answer (score -1):

"mettre bout à bout" means "to concatenate".

Comment: Une réponse consiste en autre chose qu'une traduction, surtout quand aucune traduction n'est demandée.  Voir [Comment écrire une bonne réponse ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/help). Et s'il fallait donner une traduction de surcroît *concatenate* n'est certainement pas celle qui conviendrait le mieux dans le contexte donné.